# CSV Mongoimport throws bare " in non quoted fields

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I have a csv file which contains ["] if the value for that attribute is null. For example:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,[""],6
7,8,9
```

I have two RHEL systems with different Mongo versions: 2.4.1 and 3.4
When I run this command:

```
time mongoimport --host hostname:27017 --db test --collection abc --file example.csv --type csv
```

This throws an error in version 3.4:

```
 bare " in non-quoted-field
```

It works fine in 2.4.1 though!!! I need it to work on 3.4. Can anyone suggest a solution? the CSV files I have are huge and I dont want to alter the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MongoImport 3.4 documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--type) says :

> The csv parser accepts that data that complies with RFC RFC 4180. As a
>   result, backslashes are not a valid escape character. If you use
>   double-quotes to enclose fields in the CSV data, **you must escape
>   internal double-quote marks by prepending another double-quote**.

Hence, in your case, i.e. `[""]`, it considered the first quote to be escape character due to which it is left with a bare `"` and due to which failed. To escape the double-quote, you can use it like `[""""]`. Here each double quote escapes the next double quote

To fix this, you have the following two options :

1. Open this csv in MS Excel. It will reformat the whole file correctly.
2. If `[""]` just denotes an empty field, you may directly replace this pattern with an empty string. `Mongoimport` will not create a field for the empty values in the corresponding doc.

EDIT :

As discussed, it is used to represent a null value, then you can totally replace this string using sed like

```
sed 's/\[""\]//g' FILE-NAME
```

Comment: Be wary of editing CSV files in Excel - it makes changes you may not want, such as reformatting dates.

Comment: Files are too huge to be opened by Excel so it cant be used here.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Yes, the excel can actually manipulate files in an unwanted manner.

Comment: @user3270763 you can then escape the double quotes using some script tools like sed/awk

Comment: I used sed which converts [""] to [""""]. but it still throws the same error on mongoimport.

Comment: can you show an actual data row or is it the same as given in the question ?

Comment: It's the exact type in the question just more attributes. which are just number values. This error after the changes happen in the sample I posted as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138171/discussion-between-user3270763-and-rahulroc).

Comment: @user3270763 updated the sed command in the answer. It will replace [""] with an empty string and will make the corresponding field to be set to null

Comment: Yes! Worked perfectly. Took quite some time to run the sed command since these are large csv files. Will use these since there is no alternative solution at the moment. Thank you!!

Comment: Hi I am still getting error after running sed 's/\[""\]//g' FILE-NAME .
Can someone help please?

Comment: @Sandeep you missed the escape characters sed 's/\[""\]//g'

Comment: But i copied it from here

Answer (score 2):

I got it solved by opening it in xlsx format and later saving it again in csv format. It's because excel corrects the format.

Comment: Awesome workaround. Now I can ask my users to do like you